# addEventListener, for(), index. how to use closure?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, closures, addeventlistener

I have this code:

```
var items = this.llistat.getElementsByTagName('a');

for( var i = 0; i < items.length; i++ ){    
  items[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    alert( i );
  }, items[i]);
}
```

where the event is listened, but there are `3` items and the alert allways print `3` on any of the elements (it doesn't respect the index),

Dosen't `items[i]` shouldn't do the job as closure?

thanks!

Comment: The third argument to [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) is a boolean that indicates whether the event listener gets capture priority (e.g., to make it cancelable); it does not specify a `this` value.

Comment: Also related, [Javascript infamous Loop problem?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-problem).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's a classical closure issue : you must create a new function bound, not to the 'i' variable, but to its value at the time of binding :

```
var items = this.llistat.getElementsByTagName('a');

for( var i = 0; i < items.length; i++ ) {
        items[i].addEventListener('click', listener.bind( null, i) );
}

function listener(index) {
         alert(index);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your anser, this works. Is it posible using anonimous functions only? just curious.. thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. The function that is stored inside listener is anonymous. You might not want to create this intermediate var and just replace, inside addEventListener, 'listener' by its value. Yet i think it's more easily understood like this.

Comment: Javascript interpreters do not optimise so it's more efficient to define `function listener(index) { return function() {...}; }` outside the loop then have the single statement `items[i].addEventListener('click', listener(i));` inside the loop. The efficiency arises from defining the outer function once. As written above the outer function is defined (and executed) at every iteration of the loop.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot : i edited, but more for clarity than for performances : a click handler is anyway very slow, but yes, now only one function will be created per element instead of two, which will save a few nano-seconds :-)

Answer (score 12):

No, the third argument of `addEventListener` is the `useCapture` one. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) for more information.

But you can use:

```
for( var i = 0; i < items.length; i++ ){
    (function(i){
        items[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            alert( i );
        }, false);
    })(i);
}
```

or

```
var handler = function(event) {
    var i = items.indexOf(this);
    alert( i );
};
for( var i = 0; i < items.length; i++ ){
    items[i].addEventListener('click', handler, false);
}
```

The first one creates a new event handler for each element, so it needs more memory. The second one reuses the same event listener, but uses `indexOf`, so it's more slow.